# Customize Installed Python Package?

Tags: python

Is it possible to modify the installed Python package so as to customize it for my purpose? To be more specific, I wish to modify the [Dynamic Time Warping (DTW)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) functions in [the `mlpy` package](http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/docs/3.4/dtw.html).

---

**These details are only here for your references. If they help, that's good. Otherwise, just answering the question in a generic way will be good enough.**

The two series `x` and `y` that I am feeding into `mlpy.dtw_std(x, y, dist_only=True)` are the angles in radian. So I expect the difference calculated by the function to take this into account. i.e., *0* and *2pi* should have a difference of *0* instead of *2pi*.

---

How may I go into the package and customize as so?

Answer (score 3):

Do not try to customize the function, as in any case there might be other libraries that expect the function to work unmodified, as is. Instead you can write your own function that normalizes the values by calculating the remainder of 2π. If you use numpy.array for input, then you can easily calculate the remainder of each element by just

```
from math import pi

normalized = array % (2 * pi)
```

if you use some other sequence type then just calculate the `e % 2 * pi` for each element. After that feed it to the DTW. Notice however that doubles lose precision very fast and you might find out that the `value - (value + 2 * pi) % (2 * pi)` might not equal zero however.

### Update

To normalize the values so that the difference between 2 consecutive values is at minimum, you can use [`numpy.unwrap`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unwrap.html#numpy.unwrap). However, this does not of course mean that the values are between [0,2π) themselves

Comment: But for e % 2 * pi will not help the cases where the difference between 0.1pi and 1.9pi is calculated. I wish it to be 0.2pi instead of 1.8pi. Any good preprocessing suggestions that work in this case will help equally. After all, modifying the function is the last way to go.